# comparando objetos em javascript

Tags: javascript, string, objetos, comparação

para comparar objetos em javascript, eu poderia transformar estes objetos em strings e então compará-las? o resultado seria correto?
segue abaixo o que fiz:

```
let equalsString = (a, b) => {
    let atostring = JSON.stringify(a)
    let btostring = JSON.stringify(b)
    if (atostring === btostring) {
        return true
    } 
    return false
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
var obj2 = {here: 1, object: 2};
console.log(equalsString(obj, obj2));
// false
console.log(equalsString(obj, obj));
// true
console.log(equalsString(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// false
```

se alguém puder clarear minhas ideias por aqui, ficaria imensamente agradecida...

---

levando em consideração o que foi sugerido, cheguei a esse script, entretanto ele não está correto e não consigo identificar o erro.

```
let deepEqual = (a, b) => {
    let aKeys = Object.keys(a);
    let bkeys = Object.keys(b);
    if (aKeys.length !== bkeys.length) {
        return false
    }
    let equals = aKeys.some((chave) => {
        return a[chave]!== b[chave]
    });
    return !equals
}
let obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
let obj2 = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
let obj3 = obj2;
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj2));
// false
console.log(deepEqual(obj2, obj3));
// true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// false
```

no meu entender (que ao que tudo indica está equivocado), todos os objetos que estou passando são iguais, mas o retorno é false...

Comment: Se for um objeto simples, podes fazer dessa forma; caso contrário, não. O jeito que fizeste, não funcionaria, por exemplo, em objetos que possuem propriedades que retornam uma função. [Exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: correção: 
o último retorno seria TRUE e não false. erro de digitação.